# Sample Variance and Population Variance for Ungrouped data

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, variance, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

A study of the effect of smoking on sleep patterns is conducted. The measure observed is the time, in minutes, that it takes to fall asleep. These data are obtained:

**Smokers:** $69.3, 56.0, 22.1, 47.6, 53.2, 48.1, 52.7, 34.4, 60.2, 43.8, 23.2, 13.8$

**Non-Smokers:** $28.6, 25.1, 26.4, 34.9, 28.8, 28.4, 38.5, 30.2, 30.6, 31.8, 41.6, 21.1, 36.0, 37.9, 13.9$

I have to find `Variance` for both of the given groups

### Question

As we know there are two types of Variance `sample variance` and other is `population Variance`, Which type of Variance I should use to find the variance of above(given) ungrouped data and why?

Comment: I think you are talking about *sample variance* when you say "standard variance" and "simple variance".  This is what you want, for example for Welch's test, and for each group is presumably $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum (x_i -\bar x)^2$ using the data for that group.  Did you intend to say *unpaired data* rather than "ungrouped data"?

Comment: Basically, I don't know which formula is suitable to find the variance of the above (given) data  this one $\frac{1}{n}\sum (x_i -\bar x)^2$ or this one $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum (x_i -\bar x)^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Sample variance** has $n-1$ in denominator, which makes it an unbiased estimator of the population variance.

Data:

```
smok = c(69.3, 56.0, 22.1, 47.6, 53.2, 48.1,
         52.7, 34.4, 60.2, 43.8, 23.2, 13.8)
```

Using sample variance function in R:

```
var(smok)
[1] 286.5491
```

Formula: $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{12}(X_i-\bar X)^2,$ where $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{12} X_i.$

Using R as a calculator:

```
a = mean(smok);  a        # sample mean
[1] 43.7
sum(smok)/length(smok)    # sample mean again
[1] 43.7
> n = length(smok);  n    # sample size
[1] 12
ss = sum((smok-a)^2);  ss # numerator of samp var
[1] 3152.04
ss/(n-1)                  # sample var again
[1] 286.5491
```

Now suppose I take a million samples of size $n=10$ from the a normal population with $\mu = 50, \sigma^2 = 9, \sigma = 3.$ Make a vector `v` of the million sample variances. Finally, take the mean of `v`, which should be very nearly $\sigma^2 = 9.$ This illustrates unbiasedness, sometimes written as
$E(V) = E(S^2) = \sigma^2.$

```
set.seed(2021) # for reproducibility
v = replicate(10^6, var(rnorm(10, 50, 3)))
mean(v)
[1] 9.005739  # nearly 9 as predicted.
```

By contrast, let's look at a **population** variances. If the population consists of $N = 6$ objects $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$
then the population mean is $$\mu = (1+2+3+4+5+6)/6 = 3.5.$$
And the population variance is
$$\sigma^2=[(1-3.5)^2+(2-3.5)^2+\cdots+(6-3.5)^2]/6 =2.916667.$$

If the $N$ objects in a population are $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N,$ then $\mu = \frac 1N\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ and
$\sigma^2 = \frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \mu)^2.$

Finally, you are interested in **comparing variances** of smokers and nonsmokers. I already have data for `smok` in R from
the discussion above.

```
nons = c(28.6, 25.1, 26.4, 34.9, 28.8, 
         28.4, 38.5, 30.2, 30.6, 31.8, 
         41.6, 21.1, 36.0, 37.9, 13.9)
```

The sample variances from R, are as below. Also, one
popular test of $H_0: \sigma_s^2/\sigma_n^2 = 1$
against $H_a: \sigma_s^2/\sigma_n^2 \ne 1$ uses the ratio of the variances as a test statistic.

```
var(smok);  var(nons)
[1] 286.5491
[1] 50.94695
var(smok)/var(nons)
[1] 5.62446
```

In R this **test of equal variances** is done as follows:

```
var.test(smok, nons)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  smok and nons
F = 5.6245, num df = 11, denom df = 14, p-value = 0.003438
alternative hypothesis: 
  true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  1.817514 18.891493
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
           5.62446
```

Because the variances are quite different, if you are
**testing whether the means** of smokers and nonsmokers are significantly different, it is especially important to use the
Welch 2-sample t test (instead of the pooled test).

```
t.test(smok, nons)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  smok and nons
t = 2.5747, df = 14.127, p-value = 0.02191
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
   2.254755 24.638578
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 43.70000  30.25333
```

This test *uses* sample variances, but does not display them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common source of confusion: which formula you use depends on the motivation behind the question. Specifically, are you need clarify what you mean by "these groups". Can you identify whether:

(a) you are interested in this particular sample of smokers and non-smokers, so you are trying to calculate summary statistics to describe these individuals;

or

(b) you are interested in the populations of smokers and non-smokers from which these samples were taken, so are trying to estimate the variability in sleep times in those populations?

In case (a) you are interested in the sample variance:
$$ s^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i =1}^{n} (x_i - \bar x)^2.$$

In case (b) your aim to estimate the population variance $\sigma^2$ using this sample. The sample variance is a biased estimator of the population variance *(it does not converge to the population variance $\sigma^2$ as your sample size $n$ becomes large)*, but we can correct for this bias by using the estimate:

$$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i =1}^{n} (x_i - \bar x)^2.$$